# define new getter/setter property through definerProperty create useless variables

Tags: javascript

```
var a = {}
Object.defineProperty(a, 'm', {
    get () {
        return this._m
    },
    set (val) {
        this._m = val
        console.log('val', val)
    }
}) .
```

I met some problem when I want to define new property by defineProperty, as there some useless variables being created meanwhile, here the '_m' property.

Comment: A property is not a variable? But no, it's not useless, it's used for storing the value.

Comment: What problem did you meet? What's the practical issue?

Comment: it change the original object, `for in a` now include the '_m' property

Comment: Then use a local variable instead of an extra property. Or make `_m` non-enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value in a closure:

```
(function () {
    let m;

    Object.defineProperty(a, 'm', {
        get () {
            return m;
        },
        set (val) {
            m = val;
            console.log('val', val);
        }
    });
})();
```

Note that I think this makes the code both needlessly complex and harder to debug, so it's not really worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you created it, right? You could create a closure instead of storing the value on the object:

```js
var a = {}
Object.defineProperty(a, 'm', (() => {
    let value;
    return {
      enumerable: true, // Make "m" itself enumerable.
      get () {
          return value;
      },
      set (val) {
          value = val
          console.log('val', val)
      }
    };
})());

a.m = 12;

console.log(a);
```